# How to use Rules with Profile2

Tags: rules, users

I want to send an email to the site admin whenever a user changes any of their Profile fields.

The tokens Rules offers are Updated Profile and Unchanged Entity, however I can't seem to figure out how to show ONLY changed items.

When I use any of the Updated tokens it merely just outputs what is there, which isn't much use in this case.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to create a custom rule if the profile2 fields are not available individually.

[This guide](http://dominiquedecooman.com/blog/drupal-custom-rules-how-write-your-own-events-conditions-actions-and-custom-object-custom-token) is a good example on how to make a custom events, conditions, and actions for rules.

If you have any questions about the guide feel free to ask.

Comment: This doesn't help with non-custom use of tokens which is what the OP and I need...

Comment: @DrCord Maybe I am misunderstanding the question, but I do not believe this is achievable with out writing a custom rule or editing the current ones.

Comment: OIC ty, I am looking for a way to do it through the UI if possible, but good to know it may not be.

Comment: @DrCord - I will be making tutorials on this in the near future.  I'll be sure to update here when I do.